# How to install phpmyadmin on Windows 7

Tags: php, mysql, apache, phpmyadmin, webserver

I am new to this ,

I have installed the apache server.

But when i call localhost/phpmyadmin its not coming with the proper screen.

I have tried with changing the index.html to index.php  in the conf file and has also copied the phpmyadmin file to the htdocs but still not working.

When I type localhost/phpmyadmin what I am getting I have pasted the same below , please help me regarding this.

```
    <?php
    /* vim: set expandtab sw=4 ts=4 sts=4: */
    /**
     * Main loader script
    *
     * @package PhpMyAdmin
```

Comment: Is the apache server running? have u tried restarting apache server?

Answer (score 3):

Ixg is on the right lines go to one of the following three links for an easier way to run and manage phpmyadmin.

**XAMPP**: I personally use this one and know more about it.

Link: https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html

**WAMP**: Not got an insight on it, get one yourself?

Link: http://www.wampserver.com/en/

**MAMP**: Notorious for composer install problems.

Link: https://www.mamp.info/en/downloads/

I would strongly advise to use one of these, they are great development environments and make developing a LOT easier!

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you're seeing the PHP source code is because your Apache cannot execute PHP by itself. It is not sufficient to install Apache, you also need a component that executes PHP. For Apache, that would be `mod_php`.

However, don't bother installing the [LAMP stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAMP_%28software_bundle%29) manually. Instead, you can use **[XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html)** which does not only provide Apache, PHP and MySQL, but also gives you a nicely integrated phpMyAdmin out of the box.